# More advanced file write permissions in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am making a simple UWP app that takes user input and stores it in an XML file. Eventually I'm going make that into an Open-XML esque file format which I can distribute to different people. I would like an easy way to write to the Documents folder like a normal C# application does. What would be the easiest way to do this. I considered using a sort of 'runner' application that would take command line arguments and write them to the requested folder, but that seems like a bit too much. Is there any other way?

EDIT: LOL after a ton of Googling, I couldn't find it. 5 minutes after I posted this, I found it. You can give this access in the package manifest by adding the following line of code:

`<Capabilities><uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/></Capabilities>`

EDIT #2: Alternatively you can just use the `FileOpenPicker` and `FileSavePicker`

Answer (score 1):

Your app will get rejected by the Windows Store if you include this capability in your manifest:

```
<Capabilities><uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/></Capabilities>
```

You must use a `FileSavePicker` to ask permission from the user to access a certain file on disk. UWP does not allow you to freely roam the user's machine. The only full access you have, is the applications local/temp/roaming storage.

Comment: I was just distributing it locally among a small peer group. I didn't intend for it to be on the windows store in the first place.